# SQL Select Query - Conversion Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, where-clause, sql-server-group-concat

Hi I am trying below query. Where output of ProjectID  is 1,2,3. I am trying to fetch data using ProjectID from other table.

```
  DECLARE @ProjectID varchar(100)
 DECLARE @ImpactIntakeID varchar(100)

set @ProjectID =
(SELECT STUFF ((SELECT ',' + CAST(Proj_ID AS VARCHAR) FROM PROJECT
 WHERE YEAR(Enter_Dt) < (YEAR(GETDATE-()-7)) FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
AS Enter_Date)

print @ProjectID

set @ImpactIntakeID = 
(SELECT STUFF ((SELECT ',' + CAST([IMPCT_INTAKE_ID] AS VARCHAR) FROM [IMPCT_INTAKE_REQ]
 WHERE [CNSDR_PROJ_ID] in (@ProjectID) FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
 AS ImpactIntakeID)

print @ImpactIntakeID
```

I am getting conversion error. 
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2,3' to data type int.
I am not sure where i am missing conversion. I also tried below..

```
 set @ImpactIntakeID = 
(SELECT STUFF ((SELECT ',' + CAST([IMPCT_INTAKE_ID] AS VARCHAR) FROM [IMPCT_INTAKE_REQ]
WHERE [CNSDR_PROJ_ID] in (''+@ProjectID+'') FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
AS ImpactIntakeID)
```

and

```
  set @ImpactIntakeID = 
 (SELECT STUFF ((SELECT ',' + CAST([IMPCT_INTAKE_ID] AS VARCHAR) FROM [IMPCT_INTAKE_REQ]
 WHERE CAST([CNSDR_PROJ_ID] AS VARCHAR) in (@ProjectID) FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
 AS ImpactIntakeID)
```

Can anyone please help where i am missing conversion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET @ImpactIntakeID = 
(SELECT STUFF ((SELECT ',' + CAST([IMPCT_INTAKE_ID] AS VARCHAR) FROM [IMPCT_INTAKE_REQ]
 WHERE [CNSDR_PROJ_ID] IN (SELECT Proj_ID FROM PROJECT WHERE YEAR(Enter_Dt) < (YEAR(GETDATE()-7))) FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
 AS ImpactIntakeID)
```

**OR**

```
SET @ImpactIntakeID = 
(SELECT STUFF ((SELECT ',' + CAST([IMPCT_INTAKE_ID] AS VARCHAR) FROM [IMPCT_INTAKE_REQ]
WHERE ',' + @ProjectID + ',' LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), [CNSDR_PROJ_ID]) + ',%' FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
AS ImpactIntakeID)
```

Comment: @saravanakumarr Check my updated answer. I had removed `-` from `GETDATE-()` and changed it to `GETDATE()`. It will work

Comment: Thanks Ji...It is working...But i dont know why my approach causing conversion problem though i am assigning results in a variable & using it in a where in condition...

Comment: @saravanakumarr You're most welcome. In IN clause you have to pass all the values with same datatype. But here you are passing string data and comparing with integer data.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Table-Valued User-Defined Functio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitjet/archive/2009/12/11/sql-server-comma-separated-string-to-table.aspx)n to convert comma separated string `@ProjectID` to records in a table . Then use this table in your Where clause

```
WHERE [CNSDR_PROJ_ID] in (SELECT projID from @ResultTable)
```

Table variable `@ResultTable` contains project ids in a column `projID`  of type int which is populated using the userdefined function as given in the link.